# is a PHP session automatically created for all visits

Tags: php, session

When a visitor or a search bot is visiting my website.

Does PHP automatically create a session? if so. where is it stored and how can I see it, and what kind of information is stored about the session...

Thanks!

Comment: Not automatically, it requires `session_start()` to be called in your code; where it's stored depends on the settings in your php.ini (default is normally filesystem) and/or any alternative session handler that you are using (database, redis, etc)

Comment: What's stored is a serialized array of all the values that you store in the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are not automatically created for visitors or bots. A session must be started using the

`session_start()` call (http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

PHP sessions save session files at some path on the server by default, this path is specified by session.save_path. To set or get session variables, use PHP's `$_SESSION` superglobal. php.net has great examples of gettting started with using sessions.

Comment: **Thank you** Johnathan! this is basically what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in [Sessions Introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

> When a visitor accesses your site, PHP will check automatically (if session.auto_start is set to 1) or on your request (explicitly through session_start()) whether a specific session id has been sent with the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is recreated.